# What order should I play Pokémon (on a 3DS XL)?

Tags: pokemon-series

I am a fan of RPGs but to this point have never played a Pokémon game. I would like to try it out, I already have a 3DSXL.

- Is there a order that I should follow to play the game? (there are various versions)
- The story flow matters in-game?
- There is a difference in the "paired" versions (like Pokemon-Black and Pokemon-White)?

Comment: Honestly, this is kinda opinon based. Everyone'll tell you their favorite. The storylines don't really link up anywhere except between Black/White and Black 2/White 2. As for color choices, once again, opinion based. I've always chosen based on which legendary on the front looked cooler, or gotten both when I could to prevent having to choose. Personally, I would tell you to start with DS gen, since you stated you have on, so I would suggest HeartGold or SoulSilver, since they are remakes of the second generation of games, but that's just me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Is there a order to play Pokémon?**

No, Pokémon is a game that you can play ANY Pokémon game without playing his predecessor. So, pick one of the games of your choice (game-recommendation is off the chart. go to the chat, there will be more help about it).

**The story doesn't have continuation?**

Yes and No... [Yes, there is a continuation](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/History_of_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world). No, the story is not continuated IN-GAME, as @Kendra pointed out in [her comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155497/getting-started-with-pokemon-on-a-3ds-xl#comment208512_155497)

**What's the advantage on playing the predecessors?**

[You can "migrate" the Pokémon that you captured to the new game.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4581/pokemon-gotta-catch-em-all-but-how-to-get-started?rq=1)

**Do I need to play the old games to get all Pokémon?**

[No. You can find them at the Global trade.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83213/is-it-really-possible-to-catch-em-all?rq=1)

**The games appears to come in pairs, what's the meaning of this?**

The games comes in pairs to create a more strong structure. Usually the "Main Pokémon" (the one in the cover) is different depending on the game, and there are exclusive Pokémon too. Even exclusives zones.

The idea is that you play one, and trade with someone that plays the other. So you can Fill up your Pokédex.

**Does the console matter?**

Yes, you can only play some of the Pokémon games in determinate consoles, also. Global/Local events are available only in some specific games (and as you can't play Pokémon Black 2 in your gameboy advanced or yellow in your 3dsxl ... you get my point)

But, besides that, No. The console doesn't matter.

Comment: @scenia You might want to read [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/changing-pokemon-to-pokemon#comment23493_8016) (just pointing it out for future reference).

Comment: @Jerry: I was aware of that. I think it doesn't apply to the grammatically wrong "pokemons", though. I just thought, while I was at it, I could as well add the é's. I didn't edit the question (which also has missing accents) for exactly this reason.